# Json Parsing at Swift with alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm parsing JSON with alamofire in swift. I'm trying to look loop my json but there is something wrong with my code. When looking through code with debugger, my application wont enter at if and for. Whats wrong with my code? 
I have to loop my json with "for" and parse my json data.

```
    Alamofire.request(apiToContact, method: .get, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headersq).responseJSON { (response) in
    print(response)
    if response.result.isSuccess {

        guard let resJson = response.result.value else { return }

        print(resJson);
        if let json = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
            for entry in json {
                print("\(entry)") // this is where everything crashes
            }
        }

     if let JSON = response.result.value as? NSDictionary{
            for entry in JSON {
                print("\(entry)") // this is where everything crashes
            }
        }

    }
    if response.result.isFailure {

    }
}
```

Print(response) gives this json.:

```
    SUCCESS: (
    {
        KoorX = "38.414745";
        KoorY = "27.183055";
        Yon = 1;
    },
    {
        KoorX = "38.41474";
        KoorY = "27.18382667";
        Yon = 1;
    },
    {
       KoorX = "38.422255";
       KoorY = "27.15055167";
       Yon = 1;
}
```

)

Comment: "SUCCESS:" That's not from your JSON right? Then your JSON is an Array of Dictionary. Something like: `[[String: Any]]`. Also if it crash, please read the error message in console, and if you don't understand it, give it to us.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in Swift 3+ a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]`

Two issues:

1. The array is the value for key `SUCCESS` in the root object.
2. The fast enumeration syntax for a dictionary is `for (key, value) in dictionary`

---

```
guard let resJson = response.result.value as? [String:Any],
      let success = resJson["SUCCESS"] as? [[String:Any]] else { return }
      for entry in success {
            print(entry)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code Help You

```
if let locationJSON = response.result.value
     {
      let locationObject: Dictionary = locationJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>
       self.dataArray = locationObject["data"]as! NSArray

        }
```